# Richfaces Maven Dependency JBoss EAP 6.0

Tags: maven, jboss, richfaces, pom.xml

In `pom.xml`, how do I mention that my application needs to use the `RichFaces` implementation provided in JBoss EAP 6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichFaces is bundled as part of the [WFK](http://gb.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/web-framework-kit/) product rather than as poart of EAP.  See the WFK [Maven_Repository_User_Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/2/html/Maven_Repository_User_Guide/) for details on setting up your pom.xml to work with WFK repositories.  Then, define your [RichFaces dependencies as usual](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToMavenBasedProject), but use the WFK release of Richfaces: `4.2.3.Final-redhat-1`.

Alternatively, use the [RichFaces kitchensink archetype](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.richfaces.archetypes%7Crichfaces-archetype-kitchensink%7C4.2.3.Final-2%7Cmaven-archetype) to set up your project, specifying enterprise=true.  This will setup a RichFaces maven project with all the correct WFK/EAP dependencies.